# ReactJS: Running build in wamp/xammp server

Tags: apache, reactjs, wamp, wampserver

I used ReactJS `create-react-app` cli to create an app. I now need to host that app inside Apache server which is wamp in my environment. I built the app by `npm-run-build` and copied the `dist` folder inside wamp's `www` directory. The page is blank. Can anyone help me to host app in Apache server. I don't see any errors or even warnings in console.

P.S. I've searched before posting the question and nothing helped me and If you need any of the code snippets, I'll update here.

Comment: You may find a solution of the same problem in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53816284/4704082