# create-react-app build deploy on LAMP/XAMPP/WAMP

Tags: apache, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, yarnpkg

**How to deploy the build on Apache WAMP/XAMPP server?**

I have an app created with `create-react-app` and I have two pages on this application

When I execute `yarn start` or `npm start` it's working fine and all the pages are rendering properly on the URL navigation or button click

I executed the build command

> npm run build

It's generating all the `static` and `index.html` files on `build` folder.

I moved this build folder content to `www` of `wamp` folder and execute on the url `http://localhost` its showing only the home page.  and the next page gives `404 not found error`

But when I am executing the `serve` module of npm command it's working fine on `http://localhost:5000`

> serve build

**Please help me how to resolve this?**

I have to deploy my application on wamp server all are static pages there is no rest api contents

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, your react project is built to be deployed directly into your server 'www' (root) folder. Hence you may copy the contents of your project 'build' folder to the WAMP 'www' folder and then go to http://localhost/ in your browser. Your project will be displayed.

Alternatively, you may want to use a WAMP root *subfolder*, e.g. 'www/react/'.
In this case add to your package.json file a **homepage** key:

```
"homepage": "http://localhost/react/",
```

Then build your project again:

```
npm run build
```

Finally, copy the contents of your project 'build' folder to 'www/react/'. To display your project visit http://localhost/react/

You may get more information in 
[How to deploy a React App on Apache web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461279/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-on-apache-web-server)

Comment: can be done it like this too

"homepage": "your_web_application"

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder in htdocs (xampp) named react.

add "homepage": "./", (for relative path) or "homepage": "http://localhost/react/", (absolute path) in package.json file.

And on App.js file

```
<BrowserRouter basename='/react'>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      Hello
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" render={() => "404 Not found!"} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

After configuring package.json and App.js run build command

```
npm run build
```

Then copy all files from build folder to react folder in htdocs.

And also create an .htaccess in react folder in htdocs.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

If your sub folder name is different then replace /react with your folder name.

Example - rename /react from

```
"homepage": "http://localhost/react/"  
<BrowserRouter basename='/react'>
```

to

```
"homepage": "http://localhost/your_folder_name/"
<BrowserRouter basename='/your_folder_name'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the basename attribute on the .

```
<Router basename={'/directory-name'}>
    <Route path='/' component={Home} />
</Router>
```

**directory-name** is the folder name under your xampp htdocs folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure homepage for your build.